# scss: Invalid CSS - expected mixin argument

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

```
@each $i in yt2 , yk2 {
                @include set_check( #check_#{$i},.bg_#{$i},.border_#{$i} );
            }
```

---

I want create selectors like

`#check_yt2{}` , `.bg_yt2{}`, `.border_yt2{}`

---

`#check_yk2{}` , `.bg_yk2{}`, `.border_yk2{}`

---

..............

for mixin ,but I got this message from console :

> ```
> Invalid CSS after "...( #check_#{$i},": expected mixin argument, was .bg_#{$i},.bord..."
> ```

Comment: can you make a working example on jsfiddle.com? and put a link here?

Comment: What does your mixin look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing valid strings into your mixin.

Try changing `#check_#{$i},.bg_#{$i},.border_#{$i}` to:

`'#check_#{$i}','.bg_#{$i}','.border_#{$i}'`, i.e. wrap your arguments in quotes.